# Reading in a pgm file

Tags: c, dynamic

Hello I have a question regarding reading in the bottom values of a pgm value.I have made a 2d dyanmic array and have added 2 extra spaces for the height and width to be able to create a buffer however when I try to read into the 1st integer to width+1 it does not work.Any clues why the code stops here?

```
FILE *pfile; //pointer to file
pfile=fopen(input_pgm,"r");
int columns,rows,value,line_of_numbers;
char pformat[50];
    if (pfile==NULL){
        printf("File is empty lame-o\n");
                    }
    else{                                 //Read from file
        fscanf(pfile,"%s",pformat);     //Things like P2,P5
        fscanf(pfile,"%d",&columns);     //Number of columns ,M, Need & or it will store it into address
        fscanf(pfile,"%d",&rows);        //Number of rows , N
        fscanf(pfile,"%d",&value);       //Number of value, W
        //Allocating 2D array to store M numbers
        //printf("Test");
        int **board;
        board = (int **)malloc((rows + 2) * sizeof(int *));
        for (i=0;i<rows+2;i++){
            board[i]=(int*)malloc((columns+2)*sizeof(int));
             }
        //printf("Test2");
        //INITILIZING TO 0
        board=memset(board,0,((columns+2)*(rows+2)));
        //printf("Test");
        //reading in numbers on to board from 1->/rows/columns+1
        for(i=1;i<=rows+1;i++){
            for(j=1;j<=columns+1;j++){
                //printf("Test3");   /*does not work after this*/
                int scanned_num;
                fscanf(pfile,"%d",&scanned_num);
                board[i][j]=scanned_num;}
        }
```

Comment: Problem could be anywhere. Please read on how to provide [mcve].

Comment: Note that when `fopen()` returns `NULL`, it means that the file could not be opened, **not** that the file is empty.  It might not exist, or the program might not be authorized to access it, or there might be some other problem.  It is possible to open an empty file, and if you successfully do so via `fopen()` then the pointer it returns is *not* `NULL`.

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: @JohnBollinger ah ok thanks.And when i try to run this program anything after the reading in does not show up.If i try and print something after the program does not show it, instead it closes.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be confusing a dynamic array of pointers (*i.e.* the referent of `board`) with a 2D array.  These are not at all the same thing.  Note in particular that you allocate memory for `board` like so:

> ```
> board = (int **)malloc((rows + 2) * sizeof(int *));
> ```

That allots memory sufficient to hold `rows + 2` pointers to `int`.  (And note that the cast is unnecessary and considered poor style by many.)  How then does it make sense to do this ...

> ```
> board=memset(board,0,((columns+2)*(rows+2)));
> ```

?  Aside from the fact that assigning the result to `board` is useless, what makes you think that space the size of `rows + 2` pointers to `int` is necessarily at least `((columns+2)*(rows+2))` bytes?  **Unless `columns` is quite small, you will be overrunning the bounds of `*board`, and thereby producing undefined behavior.**

Moreover, **you are also thereby overwriting all the row pointers you had just recorded in `*board`, trashing them and thus leaking all the memory you had allocated for the row contents.**  If instead of crashing at this point your program continues to execute according to the C semantics for the rest of the code, then you subsequently invoke more undefined behavior when you attempt to dereference those pointers in your read loop (`board[i][j]=scanned_num`).  Note, too, that the number of bytes you're setting would not be correct even if `board` *were* a 2D array, for each `int` is larger than a single byte.

It makes sense and is easier to allocate the raster as one big block, and if you are using at least C99, then the very easiest way to do this is via a variable-length array:

```
int board[rows + 2][columns + 2];

memset(board, 0, sizeof(board));
```

Then you don't even need to deallocate afterward, although, by the same token, the array does not survive the end of the function's execution.

If you need something you can return from the function, then you can instead do this:

```
int (*board)[columns + 2];

board = calloc(rows + 2, sizeof(*board));
```

In that case, `calloc()` performs automatic initialization of the allocated space to all zeroes, so you don't need to do it yourself.

Either way, that acquires the needed space and fills it with zeroes; nothing else need be done to prepare it to receive the data.  Be aware also that just as only one `calloc()` call is used in the second case, exactly one corresponding `free()` call should be used when you are done with the dynamically-allocated space.

Comment: Sorry I am not too familiar with C however, when I tried to memset I was trying to make every index of board equal 0 then I tried to just read from index 1 to row+1.

Comment: @What's_sarcasm, I should also point out that the `pformat` string that you read and ignore is significant.  This is the file's "magic number" and it tells you what format the file is written in.  Standard PGM has "P5" for this value.  Your code for reading the pixel raster appears instead to assume "plain" PGM format, whose magic number is "P2".  If you indeed intend to support only the latter, then you should reject files that do not have the correct magic number.  If you intend to support both, then you need additional code for the P5 case.